# IE9 CSS Wont work Chrome and Firefox works

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I am working on a site that is based on CSS and DIVs
Unfortunately I can not manipulate the HTML.

I have the site looking great on Chrome and Firefox
For some reason IE9 will not render it right.

Please help.

The URL is http://2012.v8apps.com

Comment: Could you paste the relevant code here, please? Also explain how IE9 is not rendering it right. Not all of us have access to IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to manipulate html and add a DOCTYPE as the first line of your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8" >` or `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >` in the head section

Comment: That is quite interesting.... 

I had to add Response.ContentType and force text/css for Firefox to render. 

The final DOCTYPE that did the trick is


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: awesome. Just for future reference you should always use doctype in your page.

Comment: The final trick was to add **`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`**

Answer (score 0):

Seems IE9 is rendering in quirks mode. Try specifying a doctype at the top of the page.

The first line of your page should one of the following:

HTML 4

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

HTML 5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

IE9 is also reporting that "CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch". Could you move your styles into a .css file rather than in an .aspx file?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
AND
<!DOCTYPE html>
did not work :(

Comment: I have added the doctype tag and the IE=8 meta tag.... Still no luck :(... it actually made it worse .... help

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `Response.ContentType` and force `text/css` for Firefox to render.

The final DOCTYPE that did the trick is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```